# Change comboboxitem style in runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, wpf-style

i have a custom comboboxitem style

```
<Style x:Key="combo_item" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
```

i need to add items to the combobox in run time (c# code) with this style i can add the items

```
ComboBoxItem tmp = new ComboBoxItem();
        tmp.Content = "data";
        combobox.Items.Add(tmp);
```

but i cant seem to figure out to to apply the style given that there is more than just this style so i cant do this

```
<Style x:Name="combo_item" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
```

Comment: Why do you have multiple styles? Do you have different object types within your combobox? If that is the case you want to use a datatemplate for each type and you can style the template however you want. Otherwise I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: "i need to add items to the combobox in run time (c# code)" [no you don't](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the style and then just set tmp.Style to it:

```
tmp.Style = this.FindResource("combo_item") as Style;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting ItemContainerStyle property in the ComboBox to "combo_item"?
Like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxBaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource combo_Item}" />
```

or in code

```
yourComboBoxInstance.ItemContainerStyle = "combo_Item";
```